# Sending a secret key from sever to client

Tags: ios, security, ios7, encryption, ios8

My iOS app stores its data in a file (in Amazon S3) and read the data from the file. Also, i allow sending the file in email and opening in the app from email attachment.

I would like to encrypt this file so that its content won't be readable to the client (by sniffing or when exporting to email). The file could also be sent to other user that should be able to open it, and the file will be added to its account. I think it means that should be one encryption key, and i can't use a key per user or something similar to that.

My problem is that i am not sure how i let the client know what is the encryption key.
Obviously i can't store the key hard coded. I also can't send the key as is from the server because the user can easily sniff it. What are my options?

Comment: Use SSL (https) for the key transport. Save the key in the Keychain. Your app will be able to decrypt the file with the key from the Keychain as needed.

Comment: The user could still sniff the requests (in its own device) and see the key

Comment: If you want foolproof key transport either exchange the key in-person or transport it out-of-band via a method such as snail-mail. Key transport is very difficult. You really need to come to grips with the value of the data to the user, to you and to an attacker (in $) and choose a method that meets those requirements.